# display data differently in a datagrid

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have the following in my data table and I want to display it differently as in the second example below in a datagrid. Any one know if there is a way to do this?

```
UserID          Questions                                      Answers

1            What is your dog’s name                            belle

1            Tell us why you should win.                  Because I need to win

2            What is your dog’s name                            Leigh

2            Tell us why you should win.                  I’ve never won before
```

I'd like the get the result displayed like this below in a grid view.

```
UserID      Question: What is your dog’s name       Question: Tell us why you should win.

1                  Answer: belle                       Answer: Because I need to win

2                  Answer: Leigh                       Answer: I’ve never won before
```

Answer (score 1):

This could get you going:

```
public class QuestionAnswerMap
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<QuestionAnswerMap>();
        list.Add(new QuestionAnswerMap() { Question = "Q1", Answer = "A1" });
        list.Add(new QuestionAnswerMap() { Question = "Q1", Answer = "A2" });
        list.Add(new QuestionAnswerMap() { Question = "Q2", Answer = "A3" });
        list.Add(new QuestionAnswerMap() { Question = "Q2", Answer = "A4" });
        list.Add(new QuestionAnswerMap() { Question = "Q2", Answer = "A5" });

        var result = list.GroupBy(y => y.Question).ToDictionary(y => y.Key);
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Question: " + item.Key);
            foreach(var value in item.Value.ToList())
                Console.WriteLine("Answer: {0}", value.Answer);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I'm illustrating your first table with the `QuestionAnswerMap`. Basically what you do is grouping per question to get the answers per question. When you have this it shouldn't be hard to build the gridview dynamically.